# Website remote render d3.js server side

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rendering, remote-access, remote-server

Looking for a solution to an arguably strange problem. Ok, so we are using d3.js to plot charts and graphs. However our data sets can be very small, to intensely massive. Right now most of what we are doing is internal and just prototyping. However, we do show clients these charts and draw them in real time for them, quite often and rapidly change their inputs.

Doing this in D3 looks great, but can be slow as expected. I'm more interested in what the possibilities are for this process. Go to our website, loging, and show an instance of our dashboard being rendered remotely on the server. Our server cluster is a super demon beast so I'm not worried about it doing any heavy lifting. It can do these processes about 100x faster than our best pc so it seems if we could setup our website to create instances on the fly of our dashboard, BUT only have access to that user accounts data.

This is getting a bit convoluted so let me explain. We have a database, full of millions of data points. We have about 10 user accounts. Each have access to different pieces of this data. One has access to all of it, the other some of it. All of this is not the issue we are looking for a solution on. We are more interested in the ability of our server to create multiple instances of our site, through a window essentially, that the user is remotely controlling. Like a Remote Desktop in a way. We could even start with the user login form being part of the remote render. Where our system is fully hosted and operates on the server itself, and the we page is essentially a KVM on the server in a way. However it needs to handle multiple users at the same time.

We are using Centos 6.4 lots of python for the back end stuff, php HTML and a mixture of Postgres and SQLite, but I doubt any of this is important. Just want to cover my bases.

Comment: I've read your question, but I have no idea what you're asking. Do you want to render D3 visualisations on the server? There are a few examples that cover this, e.g. [here](https://blogs.law.harvard.edu/jreyes/2012/12/13/render-d3-js-driven-svg-server-side/).

Answer (score 2):

It seems unlikely to me that you'd be able meaningfully display millions of datapoints on a single screen without grouping and summarizing them in some way. Do the processing and summarize the data on the server and ship the resulting smaller datasets to the client, which will then plot your graphs and charts from that. It's likely you'll have more than one set of data now, but it should result in much better client performance. e.g.

- {millions of points} -> transform on server -> data for bar chart to client
- {millions of points} -> transform on server -> data for XY-scatter chart
- etc.

What you've proposed is not really a programming issue, and isn't going to scale very well.